# MySQL Random Unique String

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a 'reset password' facility for a website and as part of it I need to generate a random, unique string of characters to be inserted into MySQL database.

As of now this is simply done using `SHA1(RAND())` and it works perfectly. However that **only** gives around `1.46150164E48` (for `SHA1` I'm not so sure what the unique range for `RAND` is) different combinations and being pedantic I want to ensure that a situation where two identical values are inserted never happens.

Now I could easily do it with PHP (as this is PHP-based website), iterating through a loop until a random string is generated that doesn't exist - which in most cases would be 1 iteration, but I was wondering if this is possible with MySQL?

That is: Is it possible, in MySQL, to generate a pseudo-random string of characters that MySQL itself will ensure is unique in the given table and field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also make use of UUID() global function that generates a unique value every time:

```
SELECT UUID()
```